# Unable To Purchase In App Product from Google Play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I am using in app purchase in my app, for few days back it was working however when I try to purchase through an app I'm getting following error message in dialog

**"Your payment could not be processed at this time. You may receive an email asking you to verify your account. "**

and **"Purchase Failed"** in notification bar.

I searched for this error & got the one solution, here is the [link](http://www.androidgadgematic.com/2012/10/fix-google-play-store-we-are-unable-to-verify-your-account.html) 
but no luck by this link

PFA image for transaction history of my purchased item via google account added to google play.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens and a purchase is flagged as suspicious, and a person needs to review it. Until it is reviewed, your account is on hold. It can take 1-2 days

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you give me more info on it ? How can I handle this in my code ?